# Is there a way to use decltype on a data member to declare a method argument

Tags: c++, decltype

Consider some simple code:

```
struct A {
  using Type = int;
};

struct B  {
  void test( A::Type i ) { printf("%d\n", i); }
  A a;
};
```

In real example, however, "A" is a long, template type that's not fun to type.  Even though I do need to type it (to declare it), I don't want to have to type it twice.  Even if I got it right in both places, it's the sort of thing that can change, so it would be a maintenance headache.

So, the question is, how can I declare the argument to B::test without explicitly mentioning "A"?

I've tried things like:

```
void test( decltype(a)::Type )
```

but that doesn't work because "a" isn't declared in the scope of the declaration.  If I use decltype(B::a), I get the error that B is incomplete.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you use a long type multiple times you can also define an alias `using ShortTypeName = A;` at the beginning of you struct. And then use that alias: `ShortTypeName a;` and `test(ShortTypeName::Type i)` ( that’s a common approach in many libraries)

Comment: As written, you just need to move the alias out of `A` class. Thus the code is not realistic of your problem (or there is no real problem). Obviously if `A` is the long type, then you write a using once either at top level or in `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, make an alias. You then get to use it everywhere in your class - even when declaring `a`, so you don't need to reorganize the members in your class definition.

```
struct a_long_template_type_that_is_not_fun_to_type {
  using Type = int;
};

struct B {
  using type_alias = a_long_template_type_that_is_not_fun_to_type;
 
  void test( type_alias::Type i ) { printf("%d\n", i); }
  type_alias a;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.  It looks like what I need to do is declare the data member before the method, and it works:

```
struct B {
  A a;
  void test( decltype(a)::Type i ) { printf("%d\n", i); }
};
```

Comment: Ted answer is at least 10 time better! Much more easier to read, navigate in a IDE and maintain. For example, with that solution, it would hard to find everywhere the type is used (as variable might not always be named `a`) while with the other solution, one could simply search `type_alias`.

Comment: @Phil1970 I agree that the solution with `using` is better, but technically this answers the question of how to use `decltype`.